# Android Kotlin: How to use hash password for login

Tags: android, kotlin, encryption, hash, sharedpreferences

I want to use password hash for login.
I store user and password in Sharedpreferences with md5 or sha256

```
val myPassword = md5("1234")
val sharePref = getSharedPreferences("APP_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE)
    
sharePref.edit().apply {
    putString("password", myPassword)
    commit()
}

fun md5(input:String): String {
   val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")
   return BigInteger(1, md.digest(input.toByteArray())).toString(16).padStart(32, '0')
}
```

How I getString from Sharedpreferences to use auth with md5 password

```
val user = sharePref.getString("user", "")
val password = sharePref.getString("password", "")

if (user == "user" && password == "1234") {
    //Toast
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you ask, but you cannot (well, it depends...) reverse a hashing algorithm to acquire an original password from the hash. You do the opposite: hash password provided by the user and check if a resulting hash is the same as the one stored earlier:

```
if (user == "user" && password == md5("1234")) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not store user credentials on the device, encrypted or not. If the user uninstalls your app or clears cache, they will be locked out. They also would not be able to log in from another device. Credentials should be handled by the server.

To encrypt passwords you should use a library like bcrypt. It allows you to salt the hash, making it very difficult to decrypt. Again, this should be done in your backend.

If you really want to do this on the device, this is a good resource
https://bignerdranch.com/blog/encrypting-shared-preferences-with-the-androidx-security-library/